# How should I dynamically change a project's configuration type to Static library in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I want to get a static library with Visual C++ 2015, and if I choose to create a Static library at the beginning in the AppWizard, then everything is fine; but if I carelessly choose to create an empty console application, and later change the configuration type from "Application" to "Static library", then the following error will appear on compilation:

*MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)"*

I searched the Internet but the results didn't help at all. And I even compared the two versions of project files (the "console application" version and the "static library" version) only to find no human-readable difference! So what could I do to make things right except choosing static library in the AppWizard?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you only changed the ConfigurationType only for some Configurations (Debug/Release)/Platform Types (Win32/x64) and you're building for a different configuration.

Open the project properties page again and make sure you select "All Configurations" and "All Platforms" from the dropdowns on top of the window, then change the Configuration Type to "Static library"

Comment: Ah, yes! It's really like this! Thank you so much, haha!